# select multiple column from excel in VBA

Tags: sql, vb.net, excel, oledb, vba

How can I select multiple column in Excel file using Vba. because I have excel file contains 580 columns.

I try using Query below, but its only can select 255 columns.

```
Dim ExcelConnection As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & TxtPath.Text & "; Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR=Yes""")
        ExcelConnection.Open()

        Dim expr As String = "select * FROM [Sheet1$]"
        Dim objCmdSelect As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(expr, ExcelConnection)
        Dim objDR As OleDbDataReader

        Dim SQLconn As New SqlConnection()
        Dim ConnString As String = "data source=" & DBServer1 & "; initial catalog=" & DBDataBase1 & "; persist security info=true; user id=" & DBUSer1 & "; password=" & DBPass1
        SQLconn.ConnectionString = ConnString
        SQLconn.Open()

        Using bulkCopy As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(SQLconn)
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "TMP_UPLOAD_ISP"

            Try
                objDR = objCmdSelect.ExecuteReader
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(objDR)
                objDR.Close()
                SQLconn.Close()

            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            End Try
```

I try by using select column header (220 Columns to select) ,its getting error until I reduce down to 100 columns.

```
Dim ExcelConnection As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & TxtPath.Text & "; Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR=Yes""")
        ExcelConnection.Open()

        Dim expr As String = "select Plan_Year,Colom4,Colom6,Colom7,Colom21,Colom22,Colom24,Colom25,Colom27,Colom28,Colom33,Colom34,Colom38,Colom39,Colom41,Colom42,Colom47,Colom48,Colom49,Colom50,Colom51,Colom52,Colom66,Colom67,Colom69,Colom70,Colom72,Colom73,Colom78,Colom79,Colom83,Colom84,Colom86,Colom87,Colom92,Colom93,Colom94,Colom95,Colom96,Colom97,Colom111,Colom112,Colom114,Colom115,Colom117,Colom118,Colom123,Colom124,Colom128,Colom129,Colom131,Colom132,Colom137,Colom138,Colom139,Colom140,Colom141,Colom142,Colom156,Colom157,Colom159,Colom160,Colom162,Colom163,Colom168,Colom169,Colom173,Colom174,Colom176,Colom177,Colom182,Colom183,Colom184,Colom185,Colom186,Colom187,Colom201,Colom202,Colom204,Colom205,Colom207,Colom208,Colom213,Colom214,Colom218,Colom219,Colom221,Colom222,Colom227,Colom228,Colom229,Colom230,Colom231,Colom232,Colom246,Colom247,Colom249,Colom250,Colom252,Colom253,Colom258,Colom259,Colom263,Colom264,Colom266,Colom267,Colom272,Colom273,Colom274,Colom275,Colom276,Colom277,Colom303,Colom304,Colom306,Colom307,Colom309,Colom310,Colom315,Colom316,Colom320,Colom321,Colom323,Colom324,Colom329,Colom330,Colom331,Colom332,Colom333,Colom334,Colom348,Colom349,Colom351,Colom352,Colom354,Colom355,Colom360,Colom361,Colom365,Colom366,Colom368,Colom369,Colom374,Colom375,Colom376,Colom377,Colom378,Colom379,Colom393,Colom394,Colom396,Colom397,Colom399,Colom400,Colom406,Colom407,Colom410,Colom411,Colom413,Colom414,Colom419,Colom420,Colom421,Colom422,Colom423,Colom424,Colom438,Colom439,Colom441,Colom442,Colom444,Colom445,Colom450,Colom451,Colom455,Colom456,Colom458,Colom459,Colom464,Colom465,Colom466,Colom467,Colom468,Colom469,Colom483,Colom484,Colom486,Colom487,Colom489,Colom490,Colom495,Colom496,Colom500,Colom501,Colom503,Colom504,Colom509,Colom510,Colom511,Colom512,Colom513,Colom514,Colom528,Colom529,Colom531,Colom532,Colom534,Colom535,Colom540,Colom541,Colom545,Colom546,Colom548,Colom549,Colom554,Colom555,Colom556,Colom557,Colom558,Colom559 FROM [Sheet1$]"
        Dim objCmdSelect As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(expr, ExcelConnection)
        Dim objDR As OleDbDataReader

        Dim SQLconn As New SqlConnection()
        Dim ConnString As String = "data source=" & DBServer1 & "; initial catalog=" & DBDataBase1 & "; persist security info=true; user id=" & DBUSer1 & "; password=" & DBPass1
        SQLconn.ConnectionString = ConnString
        SQLconn.Open()

        Using bulkCopy As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(SQLconn)
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "TMP_UPLOAD_ISP"

            Try
                objDR = objCmdSelect.ExecuteReader
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(objDR)
                objDR.Close()
                SQLconn.Close()

            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            End Try
```

How can I Select column that I want to select (220 columns intermittently).

Comment: What if you were to do the Excel-related functions first to return your data and then manipulate into your database? i.e. use the Native Excel functions initially.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the ACE provider and that means you are bound by the limitations of MS Access.  Access has a maximum field limit of 255 (see: [Access 2016 specifications](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2016-specifications-0cf3c66f-9cf2-4e32-9568-98c1025bb47c)).

Depending on the source worksheet, you could use a range query to retrieve multiple result sets and then merge them.

```
Select * From [SheetName$A1:IU]
```

then

```
Select * From [SheetName$UI1:SQ]
```

Column "UI" is column number 255 and column "SQ" is column number 511.

If you are not familiar with this range syntax, omitting the row on the end column tells it to seek from the starting row until no data is found in the column range.

Comment: I think its doesn't works, because there are no key that I can join between [SheetName$A1:IU] and [SheetName$UI1:SQ].